# Python os.path.dirname returns unexpected path when changing directory

Tags: python, path, operating-system, dirname

Currently I do not understand, why pythons `os.path.dirname` behave like it does.

Let's assume I have the following script:

```
# Not part of the script, just for the current sample
__file__ = 'C:\\Python\\Test\\test.py'
```

Then I try to get the absolute path to the following directory: `C:\\Python\\doc\\py`

With this code:

```
base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '\\..\\doc\\py\\')
```

But why does the method `os.path.dirname` does not resolve the path, and print out (`print (base_path)`:

> C:\Python\Test\..\doc\py

I've expected the method to resolve the path to:

> C:\Python\Test\doc\py

I just know this behaviour from the .NET Framework, that getting directory paths will always resolve the complete path and remove directory changes with `..\\`. What do I have in Python for possibilities to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath)

> Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level references so that A//B, A/B/, A/./B and A/foo/../B all become A/B. This string manipulation may change the meaning of a path that contains symbolic links. On Windows, it converts forward slashes to backward slashes.

The reason `os.path.dirname` works the way it does is because it's not very smart - it even work for URLs!

```
os.path.dirname("http://www.google.com/test")  # outputs http://www.google.com
```

It simply chops off anything after the last slash. It doesn't look at anything before the last slash, so it doesn't care if you have `/../` in there somewhere.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. The only thing that was additionaly wrong was, i had to change: `) + '..\\doc\\py\\')` to `) + '\\..\\doc\\py\\')`

Answer (score 2):

[`os.path.normpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) will return a normalized path, with all references to the current or parent directory removed or replaced appropriately.