# configparser.NoSectionError:No section:'XXX'

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller, configparser

I want to configure a config. ini and read it. When I run the code in pycharm, it's okay and it returns the result normally. But when I use pyinstaller to package .PY into an .EXE file, it will report an error:

`Congparser.NosectionError: No section:'config'`

If there are any suggestions, I would be very grateful.
By the way, the. EXE file and. INI file are in the same folder,
I use Python3.7 on Windows10

I'm a Python rookie. I don't know how to solve the error in cmd. I try to output the path in pycharm. The result is very normal.

```
# coding = gbk

import  configparser

import os

curpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
cfgpath = os.path.join(curpath, "config.ini")
print(cfgpath)
print(os.path.realpath(__file__))


conf = configparser.ConfigParser()


conf.read(cfgpath)


items = conf.items('config')
l2 = [items[0][1],items[1][1],items[2][1],items[3][1]]
print(items)
print(l2)
```

Results in pycharm：

```
E:\untitled\venv\Custom_formula\config.ini
E:\untitled\venv\Custom_formula\config_data.py
[('server', '127.0.0.1'), ('user', 'sa'), ('pwd', '123456'), ('db', 'test')]
['127.0.0.1', 'sa', '123456', 'test']
```

Results in CMD:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "config_data.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "configparser.py", line 848, in items
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'config'
[9080] Failed to execute script config_data
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be with `os.path` not `configparser` try using `os.path.abspath` or `os.path.normpath` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489459/python-os-path-dirname-returns-unexpected-path-when-changing-directory

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Rolf of Saxony!  I solved this problem by change

```
curpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

to

```
curpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
```

it turns out that the resluts in pycharm are different from those in EXE,
hopefully this will help more people

Comment: Nicely done and thanks for coming back with your solution. Welcome to StackOverflow!